# how can i get Hashbytes for nvarchar (max)?

Tags: hashbytes

How to find hashbytes for nvarchar(max), if i am using normal 
Select hashbytes('md5','std.jobText')

I am getting error:
String or binary data would be truncated.

Could any one suggest any solution?

Comment: Please provide code necessary to produce the problem.

Comment: Hi @moffeltje thanks for your response. I am trying to find hash value for the input of more than 8000 characters.